# Transmitting data rate and Receive Window Size

Tags: networking, xilinx, xilinx-ise

Nowadays, I am making a project relating to protocol communication between 2 FPGA.

When I read information about TCP/IP ethernet, the window receive which the amount data that computer can accept.

And there are a relationship between Window receive and transmitting data rate.

But in my project, I connect two FPGA by Aurora Protocol (Xilinx) not TCP/IP. I wonder that is there definition as window receive for protocol between 2 FPGA ?

I am not good at about electronics as well as networks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much aware of Aurora Protocol (link level), but it is not directly comparable to TCP/IP which is a higher level protocol. See [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

The TCP/IP [sliding window mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol) helps in providing a reliable transmission by controlling the flow of packets between sender and receiver. The Ethernet which is usually the link layer for TCP/IP has its own [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_flow_control) mechanisms.

Check the section 3 of [this document](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/aurora_8b10b_protocol_spec_sp002.pdf) which might give you some insight.